# Kinect depth image to real world coordinate

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im currently using Kinect xbox 360 with MATLAB software.
My current approach to convert depth image to real world coordinate is by using;

X = (j - w/2) * 320/w * M * Z

Y = (i - h/2) * 240/h * M * Z

where,
i = row,
j = column,
w = width of the photo,
h = height of the photo,
M = NUI_CAMERA_DEPTH_IMAGE_TO_SKELETON_MULTIPLIER_320x240 and
Z = distance

what i want to do is to calculate the length in meter of a human shoulder width, so i continue by using the formula

length = X2 - X1.

but still i couldnt get the appropriate answer.. Is my direction correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285156/kinect-depth-image-to-real-world-coordinate/) by [Divus12](https://answers.ros.org/users/34101/divus12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use following formulas with correct directions.

```
 (u,v) is the point coordinates in pixels,

  P(x, y, z)---->>>  x = depth
                     y = −(v − 480/2) ∗ depth/focal_length
                     z = (u − 640/2) ∗ depth/focal_length


x : depth, positive forward
y : height, positive upwards
z : width, positive to the right
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Divus12](https://answers.ros.org/users/34101/divus12/) on 2018-03-12**:
Hi Gayan,

Thank you for your time to answer my question.

Would like to ask which value should i use for focal_length??

NUI_CAMERA_DEPTH_NOMINAL_FOCAL_LENGTH_IN_PIXELS         = 285.63;
NUI_CAMERA_DEPTH_NOMINAL_INVERSE_FOCAL_LENGTH_IN_PIXELS = 3.501e-3;